# django keep populating Form data in table

Tags: django, django-forms

I am pretty new to django I need to keep adding form data in to the html table in same page. I can populate one time but i need to keep adding each time.

refer below gif:

[sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxSBe.gif)

What I need is i need to add the data i have added second time to populate in the table in second row.
please help me on this

## Form.py

```
from django import forms

class vm_provisioning_form(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField()
    email = forms.EmailField(
```

)

## views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from Forms import forms

def vm_provisioning(request):

     form_vm_provisoning_info = forms.vm_provisioning_form()
     hidden_values = []
     if request.method == 'POST':
            values = []
            form_vm_provisoning_info = forms.vm_provisioning_form(request.POST)
            if form_vm_provisoning_info.is_valid():
            # DO SOMETHING CODE
                print("VALIDATION SUCCESS!")
                name = form_vm_provisoning_info.cleaned_data['name']
                email = form_vm_provisoning_info.cleaned_data['email']

                values.append([name, email])

                return render(request, 'Forms_template/vm_provisioning/vm_provisioning_form.html', {'forms': form_vm_provisoning_info,'data': values })

     return render(request, 'Forms_template/vm_provisioning/vm_provisioning_form.html', {'forms': form_vm_provisoning_info})
```

## form_vm_provisoning_info.html

```
<!-- templates/vm_provisoning/form_vm_provisoning_info.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>

{% extends 'Forms_template/base.html' %}

{% block title %}Login in registration{% endblock %}


{% block content %}

 <h1> Vm provisoning form</h1>

 <div class="container">
 <h1>Please Fill details here!</h1>
 <form method="POST">
   {{ forms.as_p  }}
  {% csrf_token %}

  <section>
    <!-- hidden_data= forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), required=False) -->
  {% if data %}


      <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>email</th>
        </tr>
        <!-- <p>{{ data }}</p> -->
        {% for mapdata in data %}
<!-- <p>{{ mapdata }}</p> -->
        <tr>
                <td>{{ mapdata.0 }} </td>
                <td>{{ mapdata.1 }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
      </table>
  {% endif %}

</section>

   <input type="submit" class='btn btn-primary' value="Submit">
 </form>
</div>




{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your views. This might be because you are assigning new `values` list everytime there is a POST request sent, instead try giving it above, also you must send the `values` list to the GET method also, so it always displays the data.

```
def vm_provisioning(request):

     form_vm_provisoning_info = forms.vm_provisioning_form()
     hidden_values = []
     values = []
     if request.method == 'POST':

            form_vm_provisoning_info = forms.vm_provisioning_form(request.POST)
            if form_vm_provisoning_info.is_valid():
            # DO SOMETHING CODE
                print("VALIDATION SUCCESS!")
                name = form_vm_provisoning_info.cleaned_data['name']
                email = form_vm_provisoning_info.cleaned_data['email']

                values.append([name, email])

                return render(request, 'Forms_template/vm_provisioning/vm_provisioning_form.html', {'forms': form_vm_provisoning_info,'data': values })

     return render(request, 'Forms_template/vm_provisioning/vm_provisioning_form.html', {'forms': form_vm_provisoning_info,'data': values})
```